# do you have to reset the onClickListeners in onPrepareDialog?

Tags: android, dialog, orientation

I have a question regarding dialogs and screen orientation.

I am creating my dialogs in onCreateDialog(int dialogId).

However, I have noticed that if I create the dialog and set onClickListeners for buttons in that dialog, and then I rotate the device, inside my onClickListeners, if I access member variables of my activity, they are referencing the old activity (before the orientation changed).

So, I presume the place to reset the onClickListeners is in onPrepareDialog.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Can you show an example of your click listener? You shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: @Robby : I've got the same problem. In my case, the dialog is linked to all items in a listview. The dialog's listener need to consume data coming from the clicked item.